# jQuery isotope filter not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have jQuery isotope filtering working at the following address:

http://romeavenue.com/en/2/Tours-Of-Italy

However, I am now trying to implement the same functionality on a different site but can't get it to work.  This is what i have

http://eternalcitytours.com/en/2/Tours-Of-Italy

The issue is with the `<ul id="filter-container" class="feature cf">`

On the one that works, the code shows the class isotope being applied to the container `<ul id="filter-container" class="feature cf isotope">` and the `<li>` items also having the isotope-item class assigned.  However on the one that doesn't work the isotope class isn't being assigned.  I have no idea why.

My custom.js is:

```
var $container = $('#filter-container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'li',
        filter: '*',
        resizable: false,
        animationEngine: 'jquery'             
    });
});

// filter buttons

$('#filter-buttons a').click(function(){

    // select current
    var $optionSet = $(this).parents('#filter-buttons');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
```

Anyone any ideas.  I've tried everything to make it be the same code as the first example but nothing is working and i am at a dead end...

Thanks

Tom

Comment: anyone got any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You are  loading 2 different versions of jQuery and you are loading jQuery after plugins that require it. It needs to load before your jQuery plugins.

Remove this:

```
 <script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')
 </script>
```

Rewrite your other scripts like this:

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster --> 
<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/custom.js"></script> 
<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"> </script> 
<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/css3-mediaqueries.js"> </script> 
<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/scripts.js"></script> 
<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://eternalcitytours.com/assets/js/ketchup.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made the changes you said but it still doesn't work I'm afraid.  Same as before....

Comment: There are some missing quotation marks in your script src for isotope and media queries a=so they are not loading. Copy and paste the scripts in again without the missing quotation marks.

Comment: Your custom.js needs to load after isotope.js as well since you are calling isotope functions before it is loaded. It would be helpful to make a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: still no joy.  how do i do the jsfiddle??

Comment: You still have errors on your page related to how you are loading scripts. The scripts you have just after <!-- END FOOTER --> , can not be loaded before jquery is loaded. Also, you hare calling nivoslider.js in your custom.js file and you do not have the nivolslider plugin loaded. Remove that reference and fix your script loading order.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back and i realized that when you link the isotope script before the bootstrap then it gets overridden by bootstrap script.

put the isotope script after bootstrap script.
I usually put it as the very last script